# how to merge gz files into a tar.gz without decompression?

Tags: gzip, tar

I have a program that only consumes uncomprssed files. I have a couple of .gz files and my goal is to feed the concatenation of them to that program. If I had a tar.gz file I could mount the tar.gz archive with the archivemont command.

I know I can concatenate the gz files:

```
cat a.gz b.gz > c.gz
```

But there is no way, that I am aware of, to mount a gz file. I don't have enough disk space to uncompress all of the files and the tar command do not accept stdin as the input so I cannot do this:

```
zcat *.gz | tar - | gzip > file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what operations you need to perform on the tar.gz archive.  But from what I can discern, tar.gz is not the format for this application.  The entire archive stream is compressed by gzip, so you can't pull out or change a file without having to re-compress everything after it.  The tar.gz stream can be specially prepared to keep the compression of each file independent, but then you might as well use the .zip format, which is better suited for random access and manipulation of individual files in the archive.

To address one of your comments, tar can in fact accept stdin as input.  See [pipe tar extract into tar create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463279/pipe-tar-extract-into-tar-create/11463493#11463493) for some examples, where both GNU tar and BSD tar (with different syntax) can take in a tar file from stdin, delete entries, and write a new tar file to stdout.